# subclass uitableview cell to change separator height swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view, tableview

```
import UIKit

class UISeparatorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setSeparator()
    // Initialization code
}

func setSeparator() {
    let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: bounds.height - 1, width: bounds.width - 16, height: 1))
    separator.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 216/255, alpha: 100)
    addSubview(separator)
}
}
```

i am writing a subclass of uitableviewcell to make it's separator thicker. calling it at awakeFromNib won't cause any recreation of separator when dequeue reusable cell but can't get the right bounds of cell. by this i mean . bounds.height are only the current storyboard view device. if i using storyboard view as iphone X. run simulator using 8plus then got this[image]

the bounds.height and width are same as iphone x but not 8plus.
is there anyway to solve this problem

appreciated

Comment: Are you using constraints to design your cell in storyboard?

Comment: You probably getting problem with separator width. Try to use main screen width instead of `bounds.width`

Answer (score 0):

You need to either position the separator using auto layout, or update it's position in `layoutSubviews`. The cell wont know what its width is until it is added to the `UITableView` which is some time after `awakeFromNib` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for adding custom separator is add `UIView` in interface builder using auto layout.

In `awakeFromNib` cell don't have actual height and width of the device so it get frame size you use in interface builder because cell's frame does not load when it get called. You need to set the separator's size in `layouSubView` method(if you still want to do it programmatically). This method gets called every time when some frame size-related changes occur

Add subview in `awakeFromNib` and update it's size in `layoutSubview`. because `layoutSubview` get called many times and separator will add many times if you add separator in `layoutSubview`.